# Network: Does router breaks end-to-end principle?

Tags: networking

Here is the part of `end-to-end principle` from Wikipedia

> End-to-end connectivity is a property of the Internet that allows all
>   nodes of the network to send packets to all other nodes of the
>   network, without requiring intermediate network elements to further
>   interpret them.

But you should notice that routers (intermediate device) always among end nodes. So, as `end-to-end principle` above, not only `NAT`, but normally network with break `end-to-end principle` too.

Does it true ? If not, please explain for me why, normally network with router doesn't break end-to-end principle.

Thanks :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A router has a special job in that it must *facilitate* the end-to-end principle.

A router's job, basically, is to interpret the destinatinaton IP address and determine the next router (or end node) to send it to. A router usually does two things:

- Decrement the TTL
- Find the next hop based on the destination IP address

It should not, in general, *further* interpret the packet.

Now, a NAT breaks end-to-end because it *further* interprets and transforms the packet. NAT might, for example, change the source address of the packet. In that case, you have broken end-to-end because another internet host will not be able to identify the specific host that sent the packet. They'll only be able to identify the source address of the NAT.

---

**Edit**: [RFC 1812](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc1812) makes this clear in section 2.2.1, where it describes the layering responsibilities:

```
o Transport Layer
   The Transport Layer provides end-to-end communication services.
```

...

```
   TCP is a reliable connection-oriented transport service that
   provides end-to-end reliability, resequencing, and flow control.
```

...

```
o Internet Layer
   All Internet transport protocols use the Internet Protocol (IP) to
   carry data from source host to destination host.  IP is a
   connectionless or datagram internetwork service, providing no
   end-to-end delivery guarantees.
```

In section 2.2.3, it goes on to state that:

```
Routers provide datagram transport only, and they seek to minimize
the state information necessary to sustain this service in the
interest of routing flexibility and robustness.
```

A "normal" router doesn't deal at all with the "end-to-end" principle. Its job is simply to deliver packets at the Internet layer, which is by definition "providing no end-to-end delivery guarantees". That's the Transport Layer's job. NAT "breaks end-to-end" by operating at the Transport layer rather than simply the Internet layer, and keeping too much state about each connection.

Hope this makes sense. I know it can be confusing.

Answer (score 1):

I went through the article in wikipedia and found that there is a condition to it that it is only applicable to *application-specific jobs* not for other supportive tasks like address translations or redirecting, NAT etc. which are performed by intermediate routers... here is the part from that article

> The end-to-end principle states that application-specific functions ought to reside in the end hosts of a network rather than in intermediary nodes – provided they can be implemented "completely and correctly" in the end hosts.

So, the principle is preserved as intermediate routers are not handling the *application-specific functions* , it is the end routers(nodes) which performs these functions.

Comment: What is meant by "application-specific" in this context? Also, why would we be considering routers the "ends" rather than the specific machine on the network?